# How to use customized android automotive system image in android studio virtual device?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-automotive, automotive

In the state where files such as system image, vendor image, ramdisk image are already present,
Can I use these files to use the system image I have on a virtual device within the android studio environment? Add to, How to use customized android automotive system image in android studio virtual device?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To ensure you receive accurate and concise answers, please ask specific and simplified questions. Instead of broad queries like "How to use customized android automotive system image," detail your specific problem, what you've attempted, and any research you've conducted. This approach will make it easier for others to provide the help you need.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.